# StartupSound.prefPane on new iMacs?

Tags: audio, imac

Inspired by [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-start-up-sound-my-mac-makes) to which I thought I knew the answer, does anybody know how to make [StartupSound.prefPane](http://www5e.biglobe.ne.jp/~arcana/StartupSound/index.en.html) work on a new iMac?

I just got the computer last week, and installed SS.pP (v1.1b3) right away, but noticed the next day that it didn't actually function.  However, it *appears* to work, in that it installed fine in System Preferences, I can access it, check and uncheck its options, and move its slider, all without receiving warnings or errors of any kind.  Whatever configuration I set is remembered the next time I go into the app, even after a reboot.  Nevertheless, the startup sound is still played when I boot up.

**Edit:** Are others having the same issue?  I'd be interested to know if this is a consistent problem with new iMacs or some quirk in how I've set mine up...

Comment: v1.1b3: is that a beta release (the b in the version number)? If so, you might want to try installing a stable release.

Comment: Beta was my first thought too, but my guess is that it might mean build... The previous version that I installed a year ago on my MBP was v1.1b2, and the download site only offers one release for Intel processors, 1.1b3, under the heading "Version 1.1, Latest version".

Comment: Reading this again and thinking out aloud but does it support 64Bit or is it using 32Bit?

Comment: The website is rather outdated, I believe the author hasn’t pursued its development anymore. It doesn’t even mention Snow Leopard anywhere. Try contacting the author of the software to see if he can offer a recent build using the latest Xcode.

Comment: @Diago if you google around a little bit, you’ll find traces of people having the same problem on newer macs. Apparently the utility might no longer work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Startup Sound prefpane on a 2010 iMac with 10.6.5 and it does its job beautifully. Try reinstalling the prefpane. [Link here.](http://www5e.biglobe.ne.jp/~arcana/StartupSound/index.en.html)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure you're out of luck. A year or two ago Apple decided that the startup sound is enough of a diagnostic (which it is, in fact: it lets you know the logic board is functioning properly enough) that it needs to sound on every boot, from the internal audio device, regardless of what your sound settings and interfaces are.